# Grok succeeds in debugger and through input{stdin. But fails to output to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

```
input {
     file  {
    path => "C:/ELK/LocalLogs/*"
    start_position => beginning
       }
     }
    filter {
      grok{
       match => { "message" => ["%{GREEDYDATA:first}%{DATE_US:date_}-%{TIME:time_}%{GREEDYDATA:last}"]}
       }

      date {
       match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
            }
     }

    output{
      elasticsearch {
        index => "tst-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

this is the example on an input:

`library!WindowsService_3!2ec0!10/25/2020-00:00:26:: i INFO: Schedule ace8b126-f566-4324-aa48-a6123f81f28f executed at 10/21/2020 00:00:02.`

while working with input{stdin and on any grok debugger it fails on the output to elasticsearch.
Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error you get when outputting to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help somebody...
so I opened the log file with notepad++ and in the bottom right corner it shoes the type of encoding (attached)

then I entered this link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-plain.html

and found the closest name in the list' which is - "UCS-2BE"
Then i added this line to the input{file{
codec => plain {charset => "UCS-2BE"}
Now it works.

[image]